# pool yields 'local variable referenced before assignment' error even with .close() and .join()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I've written this function that works OK when called in its own jupyter notebook but when I save the notebook as a .py file and call it from another notebook, I get the following error:

**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'results' referenced before assignment**

```
    def get_results(inputs):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
                results = pool.starmap(aaa.dostuff, inputs)
                pool.close()
                pool.join()
        return results
```

I thought that `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()` takes care of the order in which the commands are executed, not sure what to do.

Comment: if  `__name__` is not `'__main__'`, `results` is undefined

Comment: BTW, I cannot think of a single good reason to have `if __name__ == '__main__'` within a function.

Comment: @zvone: the pattern is commonly found in multiprocessing code. Just not in a function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Exactly, I would have it on the global level and call a function from within the block, rather than the other way around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *remove* the `if __name__ == '__main__':` test from your function. You may have misunderstood what its purpose is when using the `multiprocessing` module.

Instead, put this *at the module level*, and put the call to `get_results()` in the block protected by it:

```py
def get_results(inputs):
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(aaa.dostuff, inputs)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ... other code you have to produce 'inputs', that needs to run *before*
    # starting the pool of child processes, goes here ...

    results = get_results(inputs)

    # do something with the results.
```

The `if __name__` test is rarely used anywhere but at the top level of a module. The global variable `__name__` is set by Python when it imports a module. Only when you run your file as a script (with `python path/to/file.py`), does Python set that variable to the string `"__main__"`, and it is a handy value to test for when you want to run code only when the current module is the starting point.

Depending on your OS and configuration, when using `multiprocessing` Python creates new, separate child processes that either start off with a copy of the Python interpreter state, or with a dedicated multiprocessing script specifically designed to run multiprocessing worker code. Your own script is then no longer the main starting point and the value of `__name__` will be different.

What went wrong in your case is that you almost certainly called `get_results()` *in a worker process*, where `__name__` is set to something else. At that point your function executes two lines:

- `if __name__ == '__main__':`  - Outcome `False`, so the block is skipped
- `return result` - error! Nothing set a value for this local name, so it is still unbound.

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much for the explanation!!! Needless to say - it worked. Not only that - I had no clue what if __name__ == '__main__' does :) Thanks for enlightening me!!!